# How to read a string and get values into an array?

Tags: java, arrays, numbers, sequence

I want to read a string:

> TRANS = 2'b00 to 2'b11

and extract the values 2'b00, 2'b01, 2'b10, 2'b11 into an array. How to do this in the simplest way?

For:

```
String str = "TRANS = 2'b00 to 2'b11";
```

Output should be:

```
[2'b00, 2'b01, 2'b10, 2'b11]
```

in the same sequence as indicated above.

Comment: From where did the `2'b01` and `2'b10` come from?

Comment: What did you try so far? Am i guessing right that the numbers after `2'b` are binary numbers?

Comment: these are binary digit values, it is written like this in electronics. where 00, 01, 10, 11 are the increment values.

Comment: i do not know how to read the string and get these incremented values. I am stuck here, please help!

Comment: @npinti they come from `b'00 to b'11`. They don't need to appear in the original string, it's a range

Comment: The variable parts of the string are just the `2'b00`and `2'b11` ?

Comment: yes, but how to convert the string into binary digits and get the incremental binary values.

Comment: My first try would be, get the strings with a regex that identifies the binary part, use `Integer.parseInt(str, 2)` to convert them to a int, iterate over the range and convert the int to string using `Integer.toBinaryString(int)`, but i don't know how many leading zeros you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could strip out the start and end. The use Integer class to convert between decimal and binary. Example

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Seq {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "TRANS = 2'b00 to 2'b11"; 
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("2'b\\s*(\\w+)").matcher(str);
        List<String> range = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (matcher.find()) {
            range.add(matcher.group(1));
        }
        if(range.size() == 2){
            List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
            int start = Integer.parseInt(range.get(0),2);
            int end = Integer.parseInt(range.get(1),2);
            for(int i=start; i<=end; i++){
                output.add("2'b" + String.format("%02d", Integer.parseInt(Integer.toBinaryString(i))));
            }
            System.out.println(output); // Prints [2'b00, 2'b01, 2'b10, 2'b11]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not very simple to do this because there is a lot of cases, for example if you have :

```
"TRANS = 2'b00 to 3'c11"   //you would not have the good results.
```

here is an example that split your string : (it's just for learning and not very good for a production program) :

```
String str = "TRANS = 2'b00 to 2'b11";
String[] parts = str.split("="); 

String[] values= parts[1].split("to"); //part[1] is the right part after char =

int size = values.length;


String val_from = values[0].trim().split('b');
String val_to = values[1].trim().split('b');

String[] binary_values= {"00","01","10", "11"};

int start_count = 0;
for(i=0; i<4; i++){
    if(val_from[1]==binary_values[i]){
       start_count = i;
       break;
    }
}

ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

for(i=start_count ; i<4; i++){
    result.add(val_from[0]+binary_values[i]);
}


//here the new values are stocked in : result
```

Answer (score 0):

here is one more example code:

```
    String s = "TRANS = 2'b00 to 2'b11";
    //get max and min values, 00 and 11 here;
    int max_no=Integer.parseInt(s.substring(s.length()-2, s.length()));
    int min_no=Integer.parseInt(s.substring(s.indexOf("b", 1)+1,s.indexOf("b", 1)+3));
    String [] output = new String[max_no - min_no +1];
    for(int i=min_no; i<=max_no; i++){
        output[i] = "2'b"+ (i <10 ? "0" : "")+i;
    }
    for(int i=0; i< output.length ;i++){
        System.out.println(output[i]);
```